# Comparing timestamp with date variable (MySQL and PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

Any help is highly appreciated.

Say I have a MySQL database with a timestamp column with the value "1305590400", how can I compare that with a PHP variable of say "2011-05-17"? I want to completely ignore the time part and only compare the date.

At the moment I am trying to get it working with the following but it returns no results:

```
WHERE  FROM_UNIXTIME('timestamp_column','%Y-%m-%d') = '" . $date. "'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't get results that probably `$date` has some time offset and is not equal to `00:00:00` in your timezone.

```
WHERE timestamp_column BETWEEN '" . strtotime($date) . "' AND '" . strtotime($date, '+1 day') . "'
```

or to be more precise:

```
    WHERE timestamp_column >= '" . strtotime($date) . "'
      AND timestamp_column < '" . strtotime($date, '+1 day') . "'
```

Comment: The timestamp_column contains random times, is there a way to ignore the time and just compare the date?

Comment: @David: that is why I added `BETWEEN`. Currently query retrieves everything between today noon and tomorrow noon

Comment: The only problem I have is that I'm using this in a calendar script and I don't think it will return the right results, I will definitely try it out now though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
SELECT [...] WHERE '$you_var' = date(`timestamp_column`);
```

[MySQL date() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Comment: [How mysql uses indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: I assume that this link will convince me that my solution is slower, am I right? ^^

Comment: yep. Your query will always cause fullscan. If you have a lot of rows and need to find fast - don't apply functions for the fields in your `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always convert the timestamp to a formatted date.

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1358871753,'%Y %D %M');
```

Produces: 2013 22nd January