# Mysql: Compare is not working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query runnning in php .

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT status,initiated_by,create_timestamp,extension_id,
    product_code,prospect_name,prospect_email1,prospect_phone1,prospect_title,
    prospect_company,prospect_message,track_id  
    FROM prospect_requests 
    WHERE subscriber_id = '$subscriberid' 
      AND create_timestamp >='$start_date' 
      AND create_timestamp <= '$end_date'");
```

There is two attributes names `$start_date`  and `$end_date`

My question is why above query is not returning the information of `$end_date`

Here is scenario .

I have selected `$start_date`  as 01-02-2013    and `$end_date`  as 09-2-2013  .

But the above query is not returning the details of 9 Feburary  .

Please help me out .

**Update**

When i am placing date as 10 feb it is returning me the details of 9 feb

Table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `prospect_requests` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `subscriber_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `extension_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor_number` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prospect_email1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prospect_phone1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prospect_email2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prospect_phone2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prospect_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prospect_company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prospect_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prospect_message` text,
  `create_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `update_timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `track_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `initiated_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subscriber_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor_email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=142 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Input :  $start_time = 2013-02-01

```
     $end_time  = 2013-02-09
```

Comment: what is data type of `create_timestamp`?

Comment: I really hope this isn't live; it's vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: Your start date and end date don't have the same date format.

Comment: Why should it? 3.5 is not less than or equal to 3.

Comment: @JW timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `<= '$end_date'` is basically the same as `<= '$end_date 00:00:00'`.

If you need the day itself, you could query like this:

```
... create_timestamp <= '$end_date 23:59:59'
```

*`create_timestamp BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date 23:59:59'`* would work too.

**Alternative**

Add one day programmatically and use `<`:

```
$end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$end_date +1 day"));

... create_timestamp < '$end_date'
```

**Update**

You can also cast the timestamp to a date first:

```
DATE(create_timestamp) BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'
```

Comment: thanks i  solve the issue in the same way as u discussed i use 1 INTERVAL DAY

Answer (score 0):

Dates should be in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Also, you can use `WHERE create_timestamp BETWEEN '...' AND '...'` as a more efficient condition for bounding a value.

Comment: if date form is wrong then why it is filtering for the next date

Answer (score 0):

for compare dates you should your `BETWEEN` Operator in mysql Query like Following

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 
status,initiated_by,create_timestamp,extension_id,product_code,prospect_name,
prospect_email1,prospect_phone1,prospect_title,prospect_company,prospect_message,
track_id  from prospect_requests WHERE subscriber_id = '$subscriberid' AND  
create_timestamp BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date'");
```

Please full description of between operator at [w2school](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

if still not working it then please update your question with table structure

i see your update question you are using `timestamp` field type that cause problem please see following link that might be helpfull [Comparing timestamp with date variable (MySQL and PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024938/comparing-timestamp-with-date-variable-mysql-and-php)

Comment: I paste the same still not working .I just update my table structure

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024938/comparing-timestamp-with-date-variable-mysql-and-php