# Joomla - MySQL query within a loop - I guess this is bad practise

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I´m currently using this code for outputting an array of results:

```
<?PHP 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

//Start date
$startdate = date('2010-05-21');

// End date
$end_date = date("Y-m-d");

$arraystring = '';
while (strtotime($startdate) <= strtotime($end_date)) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(tm,'%Y-%m-%d') =  '".$startdate."'";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $replyAGS = $db->query();
    $my_count = $db->getNumRows();

    $arraystring .= $my_count.', ';

    $startdate = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startdate)));

}

$arraystring = rtrim($arraystring, ', ');
?>
```

As you can see I´m doing a database query inside a loop running from a specific date up until current date. 
Let´s say that this loop was running from jan. 2007 to jan. 2014 that would mean a total loops of 2557, would this not be a serious problem regarding performance / server load??
Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Joomla but hopefully it would offer a way to prepare the query before hand and execute it with different values. Prepare and Execute is the best way IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it!
And I think this is a reasonable solution without putting too much strain on the server ressources.

Please have a look and see if it´s ok regarding performance. Note that I am using a foreach loop inside the while loop, but at least now I´m not quering MySQL in each loop..

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(tm,'%Y-%m-%d') AS Day, COUNT(*) AS Visits FROM table1 GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(tm,'%Y-%m-%d')";
$db->setQuery($query);
$replyAGS1 = $db->query();
$rowsarray = $db->loadObjectList();

$arrayforyearchart = '';
while (strtotime($startdateforarray) <= strtotime($end_date)) {

$counttouse = 0;
foreach ($rowsarray as $keycount) {
if ($keycount->Day == $startdateforarray) {
$counttouse = $keycount->Visits;
}
}    
        $arrayforyearchart .= $counttouse.', ';
        $startdateforarray = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startdateforarray)));

}
$arrayforyearchart = rtrim($arrayforyearchart, ', ');
?>
```

EDIT

Here is an optimized code i made where I only do one database query and one loop.
I use a smart detection inside loop to check for missing results per day and if needed I fill the array with zero values.
Look here:

```
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(tm,'%Y-%m-%d') AS Day, COUNT(*) AS Visits FROM #__cwtraffic GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(tm,'%Y-%m-%d')";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $replyAGS1 = $db->query();
    $rowsarray = $db->loadObjectList();

    $arrayforyearchart = '';
    $loopcount = 0;

    //Loop START
    foreach ($rowsarray as $keycount) {

    $loopcount = $loopcount + 1;
    if ($loopcount == 1) {
    $startdateforarray = $keycount->Day;

    //Data needed later for chart START
    $startdateUnix = strtotime($keycount->Day);
    $startdateDay = date('j', $startdateUnix);
    $startdateMonth = date('n', $startdateUnix);
    $startdateYear = date('Y', $startdateUnix);
    //Data needed later for chart END
    }

    //Fill the array with zero counts if needed START
    $currentdateinloop = strtotime($keycount->Day);
    $comparedate = strtotime($startdateforarray);
    $datediff = $currentdateinloop - $comparedate;
    $istheregap = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
    $i=1;
    while ($i <= $istheregap) { 
        $arrayforyearchart .= '0, ';
    $i++;
    }
    //Fill the array with zero counts if needed END

    $arrayforyearchart .= $keycount->Visits.', ';
    $startdateforarray = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startdateforarray)));
    }
    //Loop END


    $arrayforyearchart = rtrim($arrayforyearchart, ', ');
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with this query:

```
SELECT  FROM_UNIXTIME(tm,'%Y-%m-%d') AS `Day`
        , COUNT(*) AS Visits 
FROM    `table1`
GROUP BY 
        FROM_UNIXTIME(tm,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

If it work for you you have to add:

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(tm,'%Y-%m-%d') > DATE('2010-05-21')
```

Comment: Yes, I could use your query and then use the resulting object array inside the loop. Great! thanks. See my updated answer

Comment: Nice to hear that, you could convert the result to an array without any mysql queries in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the final implementation but I would suggest

First getting all the records that you want (You can customize the query to give you lesser records).

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1";
```

When you loop the $result

```
if(isset($count[strtotime($result['tm'])])){
    $count[strtotime($result['tm'])] += 1;
}else{
    $count[strtotime($result['tm'])] = 1;
}
```

This way you can get the count in a array grouped by the timestamp.

Then you need to sort it so that it is ascending order

```
ksort($count);
```

Then you loop the array to get the date

```
foreach($count as $date=>$val){
    $_date_count[date('Y-M-d',$date)] = $val;
}
```

You also do

```
$arraystring = implode(',',$_date_count);
```

Is this what you want ?

Comment: Not exactly. The output array must be for each day, counting from a specific start-date to current date, like this:

2010-07-21: 15,
2010-07-22: 21,
2010-07-23: 59,
2010-07-24: 0,
etc....

Comment: I think my code already did that, needed a little tweak. Pls see now.

Comment: As far as starting specific start-date to current date, you can do that in the query as I suggested.

Comment: Looks very clean and efficient. I will give it a try.

Comment: As far as I can see this will not produce a zero-count if there is one day with no records.

Comment: You can generate another array for the number of days with 0 and merge the two arrays.

Comment: Or you can use the same while loop in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query to the following:
`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(tm) BETWEEN '" . $startdate . "' AND '" . $end_date . "'`. This will select all results that are within your provided timespan.

Next, you'll want to loop through the results and count the amount of results per day, like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(tm) BETWEEN '" . $startdate . "' AND '" . $end_date . "'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$counts = array();
while ($result = $db->loadAssoc()) {
    $counts[$result['tm']] = (isset($counts[$result['tm']])) ? ($counts[$result['tm']] + 1) : 1;
}
```

Then finally in your existing while-loop you can do `$my_count = (isset($counts[$result['tm']])) ? $counts[$result['tm']] : 0;` to access the amount of results for the given day.

This results in:

```
<?PHP 
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

//Start date
$startdate = '2010-05-21';

// End date
$end_date = date("Y-m-d");

$query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(tm) BETWEEN '" . $startdate . "' AND '" . $end_date . "'";
$db->setQuery($query);
$counts = array();
while ($result = $db->loadAssoc()) {
    $counts[$result['tm']] = (isset($counts[$result['tm']])) ? ($counts[$result['tm']] + 1) : 1;
}

$arraystring = '';
while (strtotime($startdate) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    $my_count = (isset($counts[$result['tm']])) ? $counts[$result['tm']] : 0;

    $arraystring .= $my_count.', ';

    $startdate = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startdate)));
}

$arraystring = rtrim($arraystring, ', ');
?>
```

And you now have the same functionality with only 1 query.

Next, I'd probably move the counting code into its own function, like so:

```
<?php

function getDayCounts($startdate, $enddate) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(tm) BETWEEN '" . $startdate . "' AND '" . $enddate . "'";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $counts = array();
    while ($result = $db->loadAssoc()) {
        $counts[$result['tm']] = (isset($counts[$result['tm']])) ? ($counts[$result['tm']] + 1) : 1;
    }

    return $counts;
}

$db = JFactory::getDbo();

//Start date
$startdate = '2010-05-21';

// End date
$end_date = date("Y-m-d");

$counts = getDayCounts($startdate, $end_date);

$arraystring = '';
while (strtotime($startdate) <= strtotime($end_date)) {
    $my_count = (isset($counts[$result['tm']])) ? $counts[$result['tm']] : 0;

    $arraystring .= $my_count.', ';

    $startdate = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($startdate)));
}

$arraystring = rtrim($arraystring, ', ');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly the kind of method I was looking for. I will try it out asap and let you know if it worked

Comment: Something is not right. When I implement your code it freezes.
Are you sure you should use $db->loadAssoc()
Shouldn´t it be $db->loadAssocList() ??

Comment: While loadAssocList can be useful when you don't need to change the data, in your case you actually want to count the rows. You could also do a GROUP BY tm and then select COUNT(*) as your second column. This would put the counting work on your SQL database and allow for loadAssocList, but then you also need to change the line further below that looks for matches

Comment: Alternatively if you don't want to know about 0s, which you seem to in the code provided in your question, you could further simplify this script.